# How to find derivatives such as $\frac{\partial }{\partial p} \int_0^1 \frac{1-x^p}{1-x}dx$?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration, number-theory

I've been doing some work in analytic number theory, and I ended up deriving this expression:$$\frac{\partial }{\partial p} \int_0^1 \frac{1-x^p}{1-x}dx$$ This looks insanely difficult. I plugged it into Wolfram Alpha, and apparently it exceeded standard computation time. Is there any way to find the derivative of this integral?

Comment: What happens when you take the derivative?

Comment: @NinadMunshi According to the Desmos graphing calculator, the derivative starts at zero around x = -.91, jumps up to roughly 1.645 at x = 0, and gradually approaches Euler's number raised to the power of the Euler-Mashceroni constant.

Comment: No, not calculators. Actually take the derivative yourself by hand. It is not as difficult as you are making it out to be. Afterwards you will be left with a different integral.

Answer (score 4):

This is very easy:

$$\frac{\partial }{\partial p} \int_0^1 \frac{1-x^p}{1-x}dx=\frac{\partial}{\partial p}(\psi(p+1)+\gamma)=\psi^{(1)}(p+1)$$

Where:

- $\psi^{(n)}(z)$ are the polygamma functions
- $\gamma$ is the Eulero-Mascheroni constant

---

If you want an estimate of the integral, just calculate the series:
$$\psi^{(1)}(p+1)=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{\left(k+p\right)^{2}}$$

Comment: It seems worth emphasizing that these are effectively the definitions of the polygamma functions  and Euler-Mascheroni constant.